# How can I test functions, which use random?

Tags: python, unit-testing

It's an attempt to code `popitem` function for dictionaries with linear seqarch arrays architecture. Can you give me an example, how should I test this funtion with unittests?

```
def popitem(self):
    number = self.keys_list[random.randint(0, len(self.keys_list))] 
    i = 0
    while i < len(self.values_list):
        if i == number:
            needed_key = self.keys_list[i]
            needed_value = self.values_list[i]
            self.keys_list.remove(needed_key)
            self.values_list.remove(needed_value)
            return (needed_key, needed_value)
```

Comment: if you fix the seed() and use the same operations the "randomness" of randint() is predictable - as in - reapeatable. At least on the same machine and with the same pyton version it should be - it is not guranteed that different python version with same seed will give you the same sequence for identical seeds though. is that what you are after?

Comment: Just seed the random number generator with a hardcode seed value, and it will return the same sequence from that point on. The call is `random.seed(some_value)`,

Comment: this function is… broken

Comment: Repeatability is necessary, but not sufficient. This function should probably have at least 3 test cases, for "random" values of 0, `len(self.keys_list)`, and something in between, and it might take a while to figure out which seeds will give you the desired values on the first call.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to test the **behavior of the random number generator**, then fix the seed. For random, you can use `random.seed(SEED)`, or if you're using `numpy` you can use `np.random.seed(SEED)`.

However, I'm going to offer an alternative, a very important concept called **Mocking**.

You can redirect all function calls to `random.randint()` with a mock:

```
from unittest import mock
import random
mocked_random_choice = lambda : 1000
with mock.patch('random.randint', mocked_random_choice):
    popitem(...) # any call to random.int will now output 1000.
```

IF you're going to write proper tests, you will most likely come across `unittest` or `pytest`. These have extensive functionalities, one of which is allowing you to inject expected behavior from any inputs of an interface. This is pretty much what "mocking" is.

You could obviously put different functions in here, with different patches. You could test the boundaries, return sequential values, etc. It gives you more flexibility for testing a wide variety of possible holes in your program.

Answer (score 2):

Split your function in two:

```
def popitem(self):
    number = self.keys_list[random.randint(0, len(self.keys_list))]
    return self._popitem(number)

def _popitem(self, number):
    i = 0
    ...
```

Now test `_popitem` with hardcoded values. This will also make your tests much easier to read and control.

By the way, if I understand what you are trying to do in your function, here's how I would implement it:

```
def _popitem(self, number):
    i = self.keys_list.index(number)
    return (
        self.keys_list.pop(i),
        self.values_list.pop(i),
    )
```

Comment: you forgot the case where it's an infinite loop

Comment: @hop I don't follow?

Comment: i was being sarcastic. when `number != 0` (and `values_list` happens to not be empty) the function will never return.