# How to assert random integer values

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to test a sample function:

```
def rand_sum(n):
    sum = 0
    for _ in range(1,n):
        sum += random.randint(1, 100)
    
    return sum
```

How can I write a test case for this using pytest?

I found [this](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-randomly/issues/75), however this is not suitable for my case.

Comment: It's generally harder to test non-deterministic functions, but have you considered setting the RNG's [seed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed)? Alternatively you can: 1. _invert the dependency_ and replace the randomness with your own deterministic source for testing purposes, e.g. `def rand_sum(n, source = random.randint):`; and/or 2. test the _properties_ of the implementation (always returns a number in a given range, doesn't always return the same number, ...).

Comment: Adding to jonrsharpe's answer you can test for bounds (sum of n integers in [0,99] is in [0,99*n]), as well as statistical tests: many outputs from this function will converge to a given distribution etc..

Comment: Yes, we can re-write this fxn into more testable.
however I would like to understand if there is a way to test this type of randomness.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I test functions, which use random?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49886063/how-can-i-test-functions-which-use-random)

Comment: Or more generally e.g. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/147134/110531. Yes, there are ways to test it. Ideally pick ones that are _independent of the implementation_, so you could e.g. refactor `randint(1, 100)` to `randrange(1, 101)` without them failing.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/147134/how-should-i-test-randomness
this makes sense.